# Is there an Ethereum javascript library to work with creating and validating addresses?

Tags: addresses, javascript, library

There are a bunch of ethereum sites with alot of js functionality already, but how did they do this when there is no js library that I can find? Is there a javascript library for working with Ethereum?

Comment: The Ethereum Elements package for Meteor has validated address input. https://atmospherejs.com/ethereum/elements

Answer (score 2):

The [EthereumJS](https://github.com/ethereumjs) project includes many useful JS libraries. In particular, for addresses, you can use the [EthereumJS-Wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet) library.